# One mechanical question, two possible solutions. Can mathematics help to predict the actual physical event?

Tags: mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I have tried on my kid's textbook question (so to have meaningful discussion with him), but it seems to have two solutions:

[image]

My first calculation is as below:

[image]
.

Second solution:

[image]
.

Both calculated values are ok (no negative value, for example), but how can we tell which is correct without physically carrying out the experiment? (And the wording of the question seems to hint at one than the other)

Comment: I don't trust answer keys. They're liars.

Comment: Use MathJax to write math equations in your questions.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. I have edited and extended the initial post to provide more contexts.

Comment: The question specifies that one spring is extended while the other is compressed, so the first solution is the correct one. Math has predicted the outcome already: if you performed the experiments, you should find both situations match *your* calculations. But in the second, both springs will be extended, thus not matching the situation described in the problem.